# Detecting 32-bit mode on IIS 64 bit

Tags: c#, iis

IIS lets you run 32 bit applications on a 64 bit host using the `enable32BitAppOnWin64` setting. How can I find out (in code) if this is set for the currently executing application pool?

I'm targeting C# on IIS 6 or better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [`IntPtr.Size`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.size.aspx), which will be `4` if your *process* is 32-bit.  (Regardless of the processor or OS)